# Migration of Outlook Exchange to O365

Tags: office-365, migration, testing

My client is moving from Outlook exchange to O365.
As a part of functional testing, what should i test.
I am not involved in migration testing and it is out of scope for me.

Answer (score 0):

When the migration is done you will need to update the outgoing and incoming (if configured) settings in Central Admin to reflect the new name as well as if you have any custom solutions, apps or workflows where the old Exchange server name was used. Then when everything is updated just test to make sure emails are still being sent (alerts, workflows, incoming email, etc)

Comment: Please throw some light on alerts and workflows....

Comment: Alerts: this link: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-an-alert-to-get-notified-when-a-file-or-folder-changes-in-SharePoint-E5A79E7B-A146-46DA-A9EF-D65409BA8918?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US explains how to set up an alert. Basically you can tell SharePoint to send you an email whenever an item or list/library changes. It's a very quick way to test if your farm's outgoing email settings are working. If you receive the alert as expected, it's working!

Comment: To test via a workflow, create a basic SharePoint Designer workflow with a send email action to send you an email when an item is changed. Deploy it and then trigger the workflow by editing the properties of an item in the appropriate list and if you get an email, voila your outgoing email is working. See this link for full steps on doing this: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Workflow-example-Send-a-notification-message-d9f6a316-0df7-4e57-974b-766b318cb553

Answer (score 0):

Choose an appropriate migration method, get help from this [article](http://www.exchangemigrationtool.com/blog/exchange-migration/migrating-from-exchange-to-office-365-four-different-ways/) explains different ways of migration. Then estimate the time commitment as accurately as you can and don't skimp on the migration infrastructure.

Use a Multi-Stage Pilot Migration and Be Aware of Impacting Existing Functionality i.e. depending on what version of Exchange Server you're currently running, the migration process may impact Exchange Server functionality in various ways.

Use the Right Tools for the Job, you should also take advantage of the available tools to make the migration process easier.

Here is an earlier [thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c1088689-9439-41b1-a5ca-7f40206af9d3/moving-mail-from-exchange-on-premise-to-office-365?forum=smallbusinessserver) for moving Mail from Exchange on Premise to Office 365.

Migrating to Office 365 requires planning, pilot-testing:

www.searchcloudapplications.techtarget.com/tip/Migrating-to-Office-365-requires-planning-pilot-testing